# Know the offset of a file using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, io

I am a newbie to java. I am reading a big file using `BufferedReader`. How can I know the offset of a line so that I can store it in some other file for indexing purposes?

EDIT:
Here's my code

```
path=FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".",filename);
br=Files.newBufferedReader(path_doc_title_index_path, Charset.defaultCharset());
int offset=0; //offset of first line.       
String strline=br.readline();
offset+=strline.length()+1; //offset of second line
```

Comment: Offsets don't make sense for `Reader`s since those read *characters*, not *bytes*. You can't efficiently seek to a character in a UTF-8 file. You might have to work at a lower level and track lines yourself. The `FileChannel` class has a [`position()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#position()) that keeps track automatically. Or you'll have to read the lines yourself from an `InputStream` and keep track of bytes read.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking which line you are reading in a file, a simple line counter would work

```
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

  int lineNum = 0;
  while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    lineNum++;
  }
```

Comment: +1 You can also use LineNumberReader which is a BufferedReader with a counter.

Comment: I need to know offset, so that I can read any line randomly using RandomAccessFile just by knowing it's offset.