# Is there a way to get the offset of the current byte with BufferedReader?

Tags: java

My program has to read a text file, line by line, and get the offset of each line. I am using BufferedReader and couldn't find anyway to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by _get the offset of each line_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: It sounds like (s)he wants something along the lines of [java.io.RandomAccessFile.getFilePointer()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#getFilePointer%28%29), but for java.io.BufferedReader.

Comment: @ruakh I've tried RandomAccessFile, but the problem is that it doesn't seem to recognize new line character.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694601/know-the-offset-of-a-file-using-bufferedreader ... but that question doesn't a decent answer.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't.

There are two problems:

- A `BufferedReader` is a reader, so if you count the things you are reading / counting are characters ... not bytes.  For a file encoded using a multi-type encoding, that isn't good enough.
- If you try to count bytes below the byte -> character translation, you have the problem that the buffering level is going to read in chunks ... which means you won't be able to get an accurate measure of the current position.

---

**UPDATE** - I tried googling for an existing solution, and I've come up with nothing.  (I found a class called `BufferedReaderBytesRead` in biojava 3 that purports to solve the problem.  However, it lies.  It returns a character count not a byte count, so it won't work on files with multi-byte encodings.

Of course, if you can make the assumption that the file encoding is one byte per character, you can just count bytes ...